# How to run location updates in background continuously in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios7.1

```
UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

_backgroundTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:_backgroundTask];
    _backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

 [self startTimer];

NSLog(@"backgroundTimeRemaining: %.0f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);

-(void)startTimer
{
    self.updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(repeatedMethod)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];
}
```

I'm able to run successfully when my app is in foreground but when I come to background if
`backgroundTimeRemaining:10` it is running for 3 minutes but when `backgroundTimeRemaining:176`
it is running continuously. One thing I did not understand is why `backgroundTimeRemaining` is showing different numbers.How to run process continuously in Background. One thing I need to mention is my background process contains location updates. I'm very new to ios. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set below key values in your app's info.plist file

Required background modes : App registers for location updates!

As shown in below image and implement you location manager delegate methods in AppDelegate so that its there even your app is in any view controller.

Setting the above key value in info.plist will tell ios to enable background mode for location services.

Comment: I have already added Required background modes for location updates  in info.plist.I'm taking location updates in viewcontroller.And I'm calling that method in appdelegate (repeatedMethod) which I'm caliing using timer.

Answer (score 0):

Read "Getting Location Events in the Background (iOS Only)" in:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

Basically your app needs to ask for permission to have a background mode for this, and use the location APIs rather than a time. You'll do some setup (get default location manager, set a delegate), call "startUpdatingLocation" from the CLLocationManager class, and then get periodic callbacks with new locations.

Keep in mind you'll drain the user's phone battery pretty fast if you do this, and Apple will reject your app from the App Store unless you give a disclaimer about this.

Comment: I want to know why backgroundTimeRemaining is showing different numbers at different times.Also I've implemented CLLocationManager class in one viewcontroller and clling in appdelegate in nstimer for every 60 secs. Is that right.

Comment: you don't need a timer. If you set up the location manager delegate correctly, then it (the system's location manager) calls you when the location changes by a certain distance (that you can specify).

Comment: and iOS makes few guarantees about what you will get for backgroundTimeRemaining -- it may depends on the amount of activity going on with other apps beyond your control, battery life, or anything else in future versions of iOS. But that should not matter for the purpose of getting background location updates

Comment: Sir I got your point.And location manager delegate  is able to call whenever it founds new location.But my requirement is to get location updates for every few seconds even there is no change in location.

Comment: you can't do that when your app is in background. Store the last location you got, and if you haven't been called again, then the last location is still where you are.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `CLLocationManager`'s `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `NO`. It may help you.

For more info check [Apple's Location manger documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically).

Comment: Please tell me what is the use of backgroundTimeRemaining

Comment: Check this [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining)